# how to merge columns while exporting from jtable to excel? using apache POI

Tags: java, excel, swing, jtable, export-to-excel

I have a jtable with many columns and I am exporting this jtable to excel.
I want to show in the first column my excel sheet heading,

```
for(int i=0;i<model.getcolumncount;i++)
{

out.write(tableheader)
}
```

but its repeating for each column.
how to merge all this column and show heading in that merged column

Answer (score 1):

Use `getColumnName()` in your `getColumnCount()` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    out.write(getColumnName(i));
}
```